# Integrate Spring Boot with JBOSS EAP Server

Tags: spring-boot

1) Can Spring-boot use JBOSS EAP 7.0 server as an embedded server?

2) please let us know, if any one can the sample code for the above.

Comment: No and definitely no

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use JBoss EAP as an embedded server with Spring Boot. Even if JBoss provided the necessary APIs for embedding, given that its download weighs in at ~150MB, it's unlikely to be suitable for an embedded approach.

None of this means that you cannot run a Spring Boot application on JBoss EAP, or any other Java EE server. Spring Boot applications can be [packaged as a WAR file](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file) and deployed to any container that supports Servlet 3.0 or later.

Comment: Thanks a lot,  much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot embed spring boot in JBOSS EAP.

1. spring-boot specially designed to behave like  a  light weight container where it can independently exposed as a micro-service can  be integrated  with distributed systems.

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot only has support for tomcat, jetty and undertow.

> Spring Boot includes support for embedded Tomcat, Jetty, and Undertow
>   servers. Most developers will simply use the appropriate ‘Starter POM’
>   to obtain a fully configured instance. By default the embedded server
>   will listen for HTTP requests on port 8080.

Even for these embedded containers, there are some limitations.

> 27.3.5 JSP limitations
>
> When running a Spring Boot application that uses an embedded servlet
>   container (and is packaged as an executable archive), there are some
>   limitations in the JSP support.
>
> ```
> With Tomcat it should work if you use war packaging, i.e. an executable war will work, and will also be deployable to a standard
> ```
>
> container (not limited to, but including Tomcat). An executable jar
>   will not work because of a hard coded file pattern in Tomcat.
>       Jetty does not currently work as an embedded container with JSPs.
>       Undertow does not support JSPs.

I don't think the spring boot devs even plan on supporting other embedded containers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. With these limitations,  can it be proposed as a reliable web container for large scale distributed enterprise systems.

Comment: spring boot is focusing more on enabling light-weight REST services and not full-stack J2EE services. You can notice that in the choice of containers they chose to support. Jetty and Tomcat are both lightweight J2EE web servers. Undertow is every more lightweight than tomcat and optimized for REST over websockets. You can infer from this that spring is not interested in supporting Weblogic/Websphere/JBoss users of large enterprise systems. They just want to cater to developers who quickly want to create lightweight REST services and/or rich client applications with javascript frameworks.

Comment: You should also note the fact that spring boot inverts the application server paradigm through the EmbeddedSerlvetContainer concept. They want to help you run web application as command line jars. Enterprise application platforms have heavy duty admin consoles and other J2EE features that enable hosting of multiple sets of applications across different domains. Spring boot is not a desirable platform for solving your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Much appreciated.

Comment: @PraveenKumar The limitations apply purely to the use of JSPs. As noted in the documentation, you can still use JSPs, even with an embedded container as long as you use Tomcat. All three of Spring Boot's embedded containers are more than capable of running large scale distributed systems. Netflix is but one example of the many companies who are doing so. It's also worth noting that you can build a Spring Boot application as a WAR file and deploy it to a Java EE server if you wish to do so.

Comment: @Andy - Thanks for your reply. Can I take this answer as Spring Boot will be reliable for building as a micro-webservice endpoints and it can be integrated with JEE server for a holistic large scale deployments.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. You don't need to take my word for it though. I mentioned Netflix in my earlier comment. Here's Andy Glover from Netflix talking about Spring Boot: https://youtu.be/xU267-YHN5c?t=1937. Although, to be clear, Netflix aren't using Java EE servers as there's really no need to do so. They use one of the three supported embedded containers instead.

Comment: @Andy Thanks a lot, video which you have shared is really helpful.